# How secure are the decentralized nodes?

Tags: security, full-node, hack

I colloquially understand the inherent security provided by the decentralized distribution of the nodes that host the bitcoin network. However, is the distribution of the devices which run the nodes known? More specifically, are these devices secure? Is it possible the majority of the machines which host the nodes, geographically distributed as they are, are unprotected against sophisticated hacks from malevolent actors? (Ie random old computers with outdated firewalls)? Could a nation state corrupt the nodes?
Additionally, what is the impact of node corruption specifically?

Comment: I feel this question is too broad for this website, it needs a narrower focus. As it stands it needs something the length and depth of a PhD thesis as an answer.

Comment: Is this not something that is well understood? Can it not be generalized at least to answer the question? Granted it may be complex but… is that not a major security risk?